# How to get AngularJS Login form post reqest

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

Given the AngularJS example login form [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/H4SVl6/preview), how can I know what post request is it sending when I click the Login button?

I try to use Chrome's Developer Tools Network tab, but all I got is a GET request.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code of the plunkr, you'll find this:

```
service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {

    /* Dummy authentication for testing, uses $timeout to simulate api call
     ----------------------------------------------*/
    $timeout(function(){
        var response = { success: username === 'test' && password === 'test' };
        if(!response.success) {
            response.message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
        }
        callback(response);
    }, 1000);


    /* Use this for real authentication
     ----------------------------------------------*/
    //$http.post('/api/authenticate', { username: username, password: password })
    //    .success(function (response) {
    //        callback(response);
    //    });

};
```

So the dummy authentication isn't sending any HTTP requests because it's a dummy timeout function which "simulates" an HTTP call.

The GET request you see there is an AJAX call to load the partial `home.html` view.

Comment: On which file did you find the code above? Cannot find it. Am I missing something...

Comment: It's on modules/authentication/services.js.